# Include bot in Microsoft Teams personal conversation with other people

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Is it possible to add a bot to a personal conversation with other people?

What I would like to provide is the ability to have @bot commands work in a personal conversation with other users.

Today my bot can:

- Respond to messages in a team room when called with @bot
- Send direct messages and have conversations 1-on-1 with the user.

However I see no way to provide @bot functions in a 1-on-1 chat between two people. 
I can add other people to those 1-on-1 chats, but not bots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are working on this feature right now - it's not yet possible, but we hope to release it in the next few months.